# Cakephp 3.0 sesson time expire re-direct to home page

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How to re-direct home page when the session id  time is expire, not using auth id i have set the another value is session in Cakephp 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most probably check validity via ->check() http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Session.html in your beforeFilter and then simply do a redirect